# What is the equivalent of Apache's Action/AddHandler in Lighttpd?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, lighttpd

I am trying to run [cgi-node](http://www.cgi-node.org) on a Lighttpd wed server. Unfortunately, the [tutorial](http://www.cgi-node.org/docs/cgi-node-on-godaddy-tutorial) only covers the configuration of Apache.

I would like to know how to translate the following Apache's `.htaccess` directives for use with Lighttpd:

`Action     cgi-node     /cgi-bin/cgi-node.js 
AddHandler cgi-node     .jscript`

What it does is associate any `.jscript` file with a cgi-script (`cgi-node.js`) that handles it.

So how do I tell lighttpd to handle `.jscript` with `cgi-node.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, add the following directive in `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf`

```
cgi.assign = ( ".jscript" => "/srv/http/cgi-bin/cgi-node.js" )
```

Note that the path  is expressed as a file system path (relative to the root of the file system) and not a http server path as with Apache.